# Make sub-menu of sub-menu on right side rather than going down

Tags: html, css, menu

Hi I made menu with submenu with submenu. But it is going down rather than going right side. I am new to CSS. You can see demo [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/1boofepp/1/)

Please check and may I get some help to align sub-sub-menus to the right of sub-menu . ex: align 'DB' and 'OT' to the right side of 'INS'.

note:I need to show 'DB' and 'OT' only when hover through menu 'ECC'. Now it is showing for all others.

```css
.menuborder {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ffffff #0000ff #ffffff #ffffff;
}

.mainmenu {
  height: 0px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
  color: #266696;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li:hover>a {
  background: #11c3f1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}


/*=================
DropDown Menu
===================*/

#nav>li {
  position: relative;
}

#nav>li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav>li ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -2px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 204px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: -99999;
  top: 150%;
  visibility: hidden
}

#nav>li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
  <div class="mainmenu nav">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Ins</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ecc</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">DB</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ot</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Edu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Emp</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Med</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Med</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Re</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Soc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Assoc</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Pi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Co</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Org</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Cong</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Rel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Wel</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it using `position`, check updated snippet below:

```css
.menuborder {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ffffff #0000ff #ffffff #ffffff;
}

.mainmenu {
  height: 0px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
  color: #266696;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li:hover>a {
  background: #11c3f1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}


/*=================
DropDown Menu
===================*/

#nav>li {
  position: relative;
}

#nav>li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav>li ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -2px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 204px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: -99999;
  top: 150%;
  visibility: hidden
}

#nav>li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li.sub-sub-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li.sub-sub-menu:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
  <div class="mainmenu nav">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Ins</a>
        <ul>
          <li class='sub-sub-menu'><a href="#">Ecc</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">DB</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ot</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Edu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Emp</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Med</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Med</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Re</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Soc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Assoc</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Pi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Co</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Org</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuborder"><a href="#">Cong</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Rel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Wel</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want to show 'DB' and 'OT' only when hover through menu 'ECC'. Now it is showing for all others.

Comment: in that case you can pass a  class attribute to particular `li` and update css according to that.

check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly make it work by adding two set of rules at the end of your demo and modifying the first selector of your dropdown menu  :

```
/*=================
DropDown Menu
===================*/
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}

[...]

#nav li ul ul {
  left: 100%;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul {
  top: 0;
}
```

You can check if here : https://jsfiddle.net/1o795Ly8/

But I would recommend to change a lot of other things, like :

- Avoid using using IDs in selectors
- Avoid using element in selectors
- Avoid using long selectors
- use a class naming convention to target each element of your menu (check [naming nav dropdown with bem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297501/naming-nav-dropdown-with-bem))

Otherwise you will have a lot of trouble maintaining and updating your menu.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want to show 'DB' and 'OT' only when hover through menu 'ECC'. Now it is showing for all others.